# Logging Stackoverflow exception in azure app service

Tags: azure, logging, azure-web-app-service

Recently my web app crashed and received this screen.

[image]

We received nothing on Application Insights logs. On Investigation it was found that it is due to Stackoverflow exception due to which it was not logged. Now I am trying to find out way for logging such exception.

I have already tried [Crash diagnoser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/asiatech/how-to-use-crash-diagnoser-to-capture-stack-overflow-exception-dump-in-mvc-web-app-on-microsoft-azure)  but it is also not logging this exception.

Is there a way to log such exceptions on azure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can check the Diagnose and solve problem tool:

[image]

Check CPU / Memory and Downtimes, it should give you some insights

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics